# Как исправить ошибку "Unhandled event loop exception"?

Tags: eclipse, плагин

Когда я пишу код в `Eclipse`, то по нажатию или `Ctr+Space`, либо просто пишу и только хочет появиться авто-дополнение, как выбивает ошибку и авто-дополнение слов перестаёт работать именно в этом классе. Но перейдя в другой и начиная писать код через некоторое время тоже выбивает эту же ошибку и авто-дополение так же перестаёт работать... Кто-нибудь сталкивался или знает как это исправить?

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
>     at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
>     at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalCompletionProposal.findConstructorParameterNames(InternalCompletionProposal.java:257)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.codeassist.InternalCompletionProposal.findParameterNames(InternalCompletionProposal.java:1456)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalLabelProvider.appendUnboundedParameterList(CompletionProposalLabelProvider.java:113)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalLabelProvider.createMethodProposalLabel(CompletionProposalLabelProvider.java:272)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.java.CompletionProposalLabelProvider.createStyledLabel(CompletionProposalLabelProvider.java:562)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.computeDisplayString(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:262)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.LazyJavaCompletionProposal.getStyledDisplayString(LazyJavaCompletionProposal.java:238)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.handleSetData(CompletionProposalPopup.java:831)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$24(CompletionProposalPopup.java:821)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$3.handleEvent(CompletionProposalPopup.java:583)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.checkData(Table.java:1166)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.wmNotifyChild(Table.java:6729)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:5534)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:1896)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:5086)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4584)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1610)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2061)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4985)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5893)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5893)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2425)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:564)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4623)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5893)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4972)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3275)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.setItemCount(Table.java:4645)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.setProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1111)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$7(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1092)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$2.run(CompletionProposalPopup.java:499)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.showProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:482)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.ContentAssistant$2.run(ContentAssistant.java:377)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
>     ... 22 more

Comment: переустанови вс6

Comment: кажется подобное было когда некоректно удалился какой-то плагин. эклипс хранит историю изменения конфигурации можете попробовать откатится

Comment: спасибо, а где этот откат искать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил это проблему!
убрав из папки "plugin" такие папки:

> "org.eclipse.ui.workbench.compatibility_3.2.100.I20110413-1600"
>   "org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.500.v20110510"